# Match a string with a element of list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list in this way

```
let array = [
     { url: 'url1'},
     { url: 'url2/test', children: [{url: 'url2/test/test'}, {url: 'url2/test2/test'}],
     { url: 'url3', children: [{url: 'url3/test3/test3}, {url: 'url3/test3/test1'}],  children: [{url: 'url3/test3/test1/test5'}]},
     { url: 'url4', children: [{url: 'url4/test4/test4'}, {url: 'url3/test4/test4'}]]
```

and a input string that is a url.(e.g url: 'url3/test3/test1').

My purpose is to check if input url exist in the list without using for loop.(with map, some, filter or other functions..)

How can I do?

My purpose is to check if the

Comment: you can use `includes` method like `url.includes('url3/test3/test1')` or `indexOf` is also option

Answer (score 2):

You can create `check` function like below. It will also call itself recursively if `children` property exists. Then use `some` method to get result.

```js
let array = [{url:'url1'},{url:'url2/test',children:[{url:'url2/test/test'},{url:'url2/test2/test'}]},{url:'url3',children:[{url:'url3/test3/test3'},{url:'url3/test3/test1'}],},{url:'url4',children:[{url:'url4/test4/test4'},{url:'url3/test4/test4'}]}];

function check(arr, url) {
  return arr.some(a => a.url == url || (a.children && check(a.children, url)));
}

let isExists = check(array, 'url3/test3/test3');
console.log(isExists);

let isExists2 = check(array, 'url3/test3');
console.log(isExists2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var search = "url3/test/test1";
var index = array.indexOf(array.find(el1 => {
if (el1.children != undefined) return el1.children.some(el2 => el2.url.includes(search));
}));
```

And correct the array, because it's a bit messed up.
Snippet:

```js
let array = [
     { url: 'url1'},
     { url: 'url2/test', children: [{url: 'url2/test/test'}, {url: 'url2/test2/test'}]},
     { url: 'url3', children: [{url: 'url3/test3/test3'}, {url: 'url3/test3/test1'}, {url: 'url3/test3/test1/test5'}]},
     { url: 'url4', children: [{url: 'url4/test4/test4'}, {url: 'url3/test4/test4'}]}]
     
function findIt(search) {
var index = array.indexOf(array.find(el1 => {
if (el1.children != undefined) return el1.children.some(el2 => el2.url.includes(search));
}));
if (index > -1) console.log(array[index].url); else console.log("Could not find " + search)
}
```

```html
<input oninput="findIt(this.value)">
```

Comment: but in this way you not check all children levels